# How the main thread sleep/interrupt works in following code

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, interrupt

How the second loop actually interrupts the sleeping main thread, and first does not??
My understanding is after Thread.sleep(3000), the code Thread.currentThread().interrupt() will be executed after 3 seconds.
Can anyone explain how it actually works

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("loop : " + i);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("Woke up");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

```
loop : 0
Woke up
loop : 1
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
exception loop:1
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at multithreadings.Mainclass.main(Mainclass.java:13)
```

Comment: I searched through a lot questions/answers, i could not get a valid answer

Comment: *An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else*. It does not actually stop the thread immediately. As a result, the first loop succeeds, but since you interrupted in the first loop, the second loop does not perform `Thread#sleep`. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: But as you said if the thread is interrupted. How did the execution enter the second loop?

Comment: Like I quoted, its an *indication*, its not immediate.

Comment: when`i = 1` the interruption flag is already set so `Thread.sleep` will throw exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interruption is a polite request to stop: a Thread is under no obligation to stop.

It's like the Robin Williams joke about [what police in the UK say when you commit a crime](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/79550):

> Stop! Or I'll say stop again!

Also, interrupting a thread doesn't cause an `InterruptedException` to be thrown: it merely sets a flag on the thread. If something (like `Thread.sleep`) checks this flag, and finds that it is set, it may then throw an `InterruptedException`; but the flag and exception are two orthogonal ways of indicating interruption.

As such:

- On the first execution, you sleep for 3 seconds, then set the interrupted flag, and the loop body finishes normally.
- On the second execution, you ask to sleep for 3 seconds, but `Thread.sleep` detects the interrupted flag, and throws the exception.

Comment: "the exception affords the thread an opportunity to promptly check the flag" this is not correct. The `InterruptedException` itself indicates that the thread was interrupted; the fact `InterruptedException` is thrown does not mean the interrupted flag is set. Indeed, it is often explicitly cleared before throwing, because IE is often thrown like `if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();`, and [`Thread.interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) clears the flag. But the flag *can* be set.

Answer (score 2):

There is a single thread involved in the code you posted. This thread executes a loop. At the first iteration, the thread interrupts itself. Interrupting doesn't mean "stop executing immediately". It means: "please, I would like you to stop running when you can".

A thread that wants to respect interruption requests can do it in two ways:

1. It regularly checks if it has been interrupted, and if it's the case, then it stops executing (by breaking out of a loop or returning, for example)
2. It calls a blocking method such as `sleep()`, which will throw an InterruptedException if the thread has been interrupted or is being interrupted.

What happens is the second case. A request for interruption is done in the first iteration, after the call to sleep(). The thread continues running, and at the second iteration, it calls sleep(), which throws en InterruptedException because the thread has been interrupted before.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, one **thread** cannot stop the other thread. A thread can only request the other thread to stop. The request is made in the form of an **interruption**. Calling the *interrupt()* method on an instance of a Thread sets the interrupt status state as **true** on the instance.

All blocking methods respond to interruption by throwing InterruptedException once the interrupt status is set **to true.** , if you want to check more in detail, please read the below article. See how [Thread Interruption](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java)  works in Java.

Comment: One Java thread [_can_ stop another](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()). It's just a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--):

> Interrupts this thread.
>
> Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, ...
>
> If this thread is blocked ...
>
> If this thread is blocked ...
>
> If this thread is blocked ...
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this **thread's *interrupt status* will be set**.

and [`sleep(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-):

> Throws `InterruptedException` if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The *interrupted status* of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

Since the thread has already interrupted itself on the second iteration of the loop, thereby setting it's own *interrupted status*, the `sleep(...)` method is immediately interrupted.